# ddd does not see ubuntu font, although gdb does see it

Tags: fonts

I am using gdb for APL interpreter development, but
would like to use ddd, instead. ddd appears to require that
its fonts come from X, rather than from the normal
set of fonts visible in Ubuntu.
I have the Apl385.ttf font installed in 
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dyalog/Apl385.ttf,
but ddd does not show it in its Preferences/Fonts page.

Hence, APL symbols such as iota(⍳) do not display under ddd.
So...

1. Is there a way to get a truetype font installed under
   X on Ubuntu 16.04LTS, so that I can select it from ddd?
2. Is there a better graphical debugger than ddd available
   that will not have this problem?
   [ I do not particularly like ddd, but I like gdb less.]

If both of these answers are NO, then I'll go back to using
gdb.

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Are you using an X fontserver?  Did you reconfigure it to serve your truetype fonts instead of the defaults?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying... To the best of my knowledge, I am not using an X fontserver. In fact, I have no idea what an X fontserver might be. I installed the new fonts  here: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dyalog/    Suggestions welcome!